# MvcReportViewer export to PDF only first page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I have MvcReportViewer component, which I use for reports.

In new version of MvcReportViewer js `printReport` is like this:

```
function printReport() {
    $find('ReportViewer').exportReport('PDF');
}
```

Is there a possibility to export PDF only first page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created seperate report (which has subreport of the first page) made changes in MvcReportViewer.js:

```
function printReport() {
    if ($('.printOtherUrl').length > 0) {
        window.open($('.printOtherUrl').val(), '_blank');
    } else {
        $find('ReportViewer').exportReport('PDF');
    }
}
```

In a View that i show my `@Html.MvcReportViewer`:

When iframe is loaded (i have 500ms setTimeout for height and width too, then i add this input):

```
$("<input type='hidden' class='printOtherUrl'>").val('@Url.Action(Mvc.Reports.GetDailyReportFirstPage())').appendTo($this.contents().find('body'));
```

And made ie print button hidden per `ShowPrintButton = false` of `ControlSettings`

And my controller action is :

```
public virtual ActionResult GetDailyReportFirstPage()
{
    return this.Report(
        ReportFormat.Excel,
        SiteReports.DailySummaryMainReport,
        new { genDate = Clock.Now() });
}
```